# Why is typeof(Child<>).BaseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition false?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Example:

```
class Base<T>{}
class Child<T> : Base<T>{}

typeof( Base<> ).IsGenericTypeDefinition; // == true ie. parameterless 
typeof( Child<> ).BaseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition; // == false wtf???

// Eventually 
typeof( Base<> ) != typeof( Child<> ).BaseType;
```

Due to this feature `typeof( Child<> ).IsSubclassOf( typeof( Base<> ) )` is not working.

Comment: `typeof( Base<> ).GetGenericArguments()[0].DeclaringType` vs. `typeof( Child<> ).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0].DeclaringType`. Generic type definition is `Base<T (from Base<>)>`, but your `Child<T (from Child<>)>` inherit from `Base<T (from Child<>)>`. That two `T` are different, even though them have the same name.

Comment: These are "open types", not yet specialized with a specific type parameter.  There is no inheritance relationship at all between, say, `Child<T>` and `Base<U>`, they only have System.Object in common.  It is not obvious why you want to use open types.

Comment: Rather than jumping straight to "I thought this would fix my problem, but it's not working as I expected it to", explain *what problem you're trying to solve*. Having to muck about with a combination of generics *and* reflection is rarely right.

Answer (score 3):

I have read the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) and it explains the differences between `IsGenericType` and `IsGenericTypeDefinition`.

Your `BaseType` falls into this category: open constructed type

> The ContainsGenericParameters property is **true**.
>
> Examples are a generic type that has unassigned type parameters, ***a
>   type that is nested in a generic type definition*** or in an open
>   constructed type, or a generic type that has a type argument for which
>   the ContainsGenericParameters property is true.
>
> **It is not possible to create an instance of an open constructed type**.

So in order for a type definition to be generic you must be able to create an instance from it. But in this case, `BaseType` is an open constructed type and it is bound to it's inheritor: `Child<T>`, If you create a `Child<int>` then the base becomes `Base<int>`, not vice versa.

Therefore you can't create a generic type instance directly from the `BaseType`  by calling `MakeGenericType` because it's type parameter is declared in the inheritor class `Child<T>`.

Comment: Hi! ``` If you create a Child<int> then the base becomes Base<int>``` it's a good explanation. But it's also necessary to add that parameterless generic type does have parameter types. Which are also inherited.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some information in the book `Professional .NET 2.0 Generics`, section `Reflection and Generic Inheritance`.

> the inherited type is bound indirectly to the TValue parameter of the subclass.

I did some simple tests:

```
  var arg = typeof( Base<> ).GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
  Console.WriteLine( arg.DeclaringType ); // Base`1[T]

  arg = typeof( Child<> ).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
  Console.WriteLine( arg.DeclaringType ); // Child`1[T]
```

Term "parameterless" confused me. 
Actually even types with no specified generic parameters have parameters. It's types with `arg.IsGenericParameter == true`.

And these types can also be inherited. As in the usual case:

```
typeof( Child<int> ).BaseType == typeof( Base<int> );
```

The same way with parameterless case:

```
typeof( Base<> ) != typeof( Child<> ).BaseType; // it's something like: Base<T>.T !=  Child<T>.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just using `BaseType`, you need to **also** use [GetGenericTypeDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var g = typeof(Base<>).IsGenericTypeDefinition; 
var h = typeof(Child<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsGenericTypeDefinition;
var i = typeof(Base<>) == typeof(Child<>).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

*[Reflection and Generic Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection-and-generic-types#examining-type-arguments-and-type-parameters) discusses some of the complexities involved with reflection in the context of generics.*